# Owin Authentication WS-Federation Fails Due To SecurityTokenHandlers

Tags: asp.net, token, owin, acs, ws-federation

I'm trying to authenticate toward an ACS server using OWIN in MVC 5. My process is based off an authentication with http modules the old way through the config files but I can't get it to work with OWIN and get this error:

> IDX10201: None of the SecurityTokenHandlers could read the 'securityToken'

Here are the relevant parts of my startup:

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(
            new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType =
                    WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
            });
app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
            new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                MetadataAddress =
                    "https://*******.accesscontrol.windows.net/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml",
                Wtrealm = "http://localhost:62569/",
                Wreply = "http://localhost:62569/callback-signin",
                SecurityTokenHandlers = new SecurityTokenHandlerCollection
                {
                    new MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler
                    {
                        Configuration = new SecurityTokenHandlerConfiguration
                        {
                            CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None,
                            IssuerNameRegistry = new ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry
                            {
                                IssuingAuthorities =
                                    new List<IssuingAuthority>
                                    {
                                        new IssuingAuthority("https://*******.accesscontrol.windows.net/")
                                        {
                                            Thumbprints = { "9B9F8B5E21640ED692C*****A62B4077813659B5" },
                                            Issuers = { "https://*******.accesscontrol.windows.net/" }
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

And here is the working config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />    
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=********.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=*********;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=m*******;Password=*******" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  
  
  
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>


 <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="http://localhost:62569" />
      </audienceUris>
      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <add type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </securityTokenHandlers>
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
      <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry">
        <authority name="https://**********.accesscontrol.windows.net/">
          <keys>
            <add thumbprint="9B9F8B5E21640ED692CC1CF2A62B4077813659B5" />
          </keys>
          <validIssuers>
            <add name="https://*********.accesscontrol.windows.net/" />
          </validIssuers>
        </authority>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
      <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://***********.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/wsfederation" realm="http://localhost:62569" reply="http://localhost:62569/callback-signin" requireHttps="false" />
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>      
  
      <entityFramework>
        <providers>
          <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
          <parameters>
            <parameter value="Data Source=***********.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=********;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=*************;Password=********" />
          </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
      </entityFramework>
      
    </configuration>
```

**Full Owin Errors**

> 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenValidationException' in
> mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: IDX10201: None of the the
> SecurityTokenHandlers could read the 'securityToken':

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Assertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_19fb92df-c8ac-4388-9294-7a8cdb3bcf0b" IssueInstant="2015-07-30T12:07:25.837Z" Version="2.0">
   <Issuer>https://*********.accesscontrol.windows.net/</Issuer>
   <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <ds:SignedInfo>
         <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
         <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
         <ds:Reference URI="#_19fb92df-c8ac-4388-9294-7a8cdb3bcf0b">
            <ds:Transforms>
               <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
               <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <ds:DigestValue>wEjAPR2kWtfrRKX9tMGvJu/Nv+yLtm1KeXbYFDwbB8U=</ds:DigestValue>
         </ds:Reference>
      </ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:SignatureValue>GVamldoBjB+RZY+2bf2700k2Z4PUtp+7Cy9EGTne5+7ID+tLmQ08yXur898O21ldqVqqmGxKbVYQRPVRkF1F+e3bBRipEhyvZ4K8oxQly6f0lLza2svTBSI8GUhLQ9/5ElReaOAgM84q3V5XcBvmXHamanRFSd5hzkTqWbRlNFWJFisqKEuTBTl2DLNV/CeWKrv+11qTgGc0Qxk18mycDGXDfwuWAYcVAZMImiEFm8wErIfOaQ9EbKYqtoVdbuKb5WH2+yjI6jp7uHRKl6x2z77XVLuNRLbutgQDASMGt2dll4P7Ve/tt/NqzkHj7P/zbkEYckY6r1W2Tv1kUeh6vg==</ds:SignatureValue>
      <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
         <X509Data>
            <X509Certificate>MIIDSjCCAjagAwIBAgIQrcBhMtovuJ9MilbEjMjS7TAJBgUrDgMCHQUAMDExLzAtBgNVBAMTJm1hcmdvY29uc2VpbC5hY2Nlc3Njb250cm9sLndpbmRvd3MubmV0MB4XDTE1MDYxNjA4MTYzOFoXDTIwMDUzMTIyMDAwMFowMTEvMC0GA1UEAxMmbWFyZ29jb25zZWlsLmFjY2Vzc2NvbnRyb2wud2luZG93cy5uZXQwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQCpeZseXX1IYTABUOPr7nfIAXc7cXAI0k+vR3qEbvy0UxEhYAkAocQR2qUTPQ8D1v4lPp59tnHKBGJ0eHt9DYm/SyKkfHsWfqsysZx5NHXSJIhy/SgHwpd8b2q1NKxqBRLrdJKyAua+WWza4p/HMFjEVoN/upZtngSqxUKO/oYqy6m7smkz8vwjzpJR8tyqN881XBQzvryiF/i3ZPFQqlCT9263TMcAGPpym9uvxHzFPPx3u8IDz3AQydyHeViaJhiXGic0VEcm6LMn3JLOYqAzJnv8z89NdpsL4ynv1ekytt/8yyza3CnsU1E4tFDj1HU3785aFZ1xm6wr1MUK9VOTAgMBAAGjZjBkMGIGA1UdAQRbMFmAEN1alzwM3lJSHdh4LFl7uxmhMzAxMS8wLQYDVQQDEyZtYXJnb2NvbnNlaWwuYWNjZXNzY29udHJvbC53aW5kb3dzLm5ldIIQrcBhMtovuJ9MilbEjMjS7TAJBgUrDgMCHQUAA4IBAQAsQ5jNKvS2fLtqs9oB6DGTXdI5nAli5UyvZUQlnf******ifG14SRbVdTjUOzngIWAJ5KAQk5t//wSkwgAS+U6AFYI/mee9NLEvOEhrRbpGUP0oL504OZ9zTDeXmGu2FybRB2TvdTKLaeVsBvwqgP33QFkcuPK50fCGC1l3SecIeyWL5fsiw/2+GuTKHjCaeRqnYBgDTINptc9PGayLPBTjs4UPzbccmaYyuanmTAMZGU0iRoGJYet2uAasT52QvWZqD0NUZbWyR1N8CBf5EIW2S/TrpoOBYNgZQU5n9PRJjTBhESHXjfa8RipC8RXU9o</X509Certificate>
         </X509Data>
      </KeyInfo>
   </ds:Signature>
   <Subject>
      <NameID>******.*******@********.net</NameID>
      <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer" />
   </Subject>
   <Conditions NotBefore="2015-07-30T12:07:25.837Z" NotOnOrAfter="2015-07-30T13:07:25.837Z">
      <AudienceRestriction>
         <Audience>http://localhost:62569/</Audience>
      </AudienceRestriction>
   </Conditions>
   <AttributeStatement>
      <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid">
         <AttributeValue>7102feaa-34af-4756-85ce-b0f69766d78d</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
      <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name">
         <AttributeValue>*****.*******@*******.net</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
      <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname">
         <AttributeValue>******</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
      <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname">
         <AttributeValue>*******</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
      <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider">
         <AttributeValue>https://sts.windows.net/7102feaa-34af-4756-85ce-b0f69766d78d/</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
      <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider">
         <AttributeValue>https://sts.windows.net/7102feaa-34af-4756-85ce-b0f69766d78d/</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
   </AttributeStatement>
   <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2015-07-27T12:39:30.003Z">
      <AuthnContext>
         <AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</AuthnContextClassRef>
      </AuthnContext>
   </AuthnStatement>
</Assertion>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you specify the `SecurityTokenHandlers` property to the WS-Federation middlware, you are giving it the definitive list of security token handlers it should use to validate any security tokens it receives, preventing creation of the default token handlers.

By specifying a `MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler` instance, the middleware can only validate `SessionSecurityToken` instances. This type of token is used for passing session data. You won't see this token in the messages received from Azure AD, so the middleware message is accurate: it cannot read the security token.

The management of an authenticated session is handled by the cookie middleware - it will issue a "logged in" cookie once you sign in with your external authentication. You shouldn't need to specify an `AuthenticationType` value unless you're using multiple authentication cookies.

Instead, you need to tell the WS-Federation middleware to perform sign-in using the cookie authentication middleware, using the [`SignInAsAuthenticationType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.wsfederation.wsfederationauthenticationoptions.signinasauthenticationtype%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) option. This means that after validating the sign-in message from the Azure AD tenant, it will trigger the cookie authentication middleware to add a cookie to the response. That cookie is then used on subsequent requests to sign in the user with their identity from Azure AD.

The configuration will look like this:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(
    new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
    new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
    {
        SignInAsAuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
        MetadataAddress = "https://*******.accesscontrol.windows.net/"
             + "FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml",
        Wtrealm = "http://localhost:62569/",
        Wreply = "http://localhost:62569/callback-signin"
    });
```

Because you have specified the metadata address, the middleware would normally be able to retrieve all the information it requires to validate the tokens returned by your Azure AD tenant. Unfortunately this seems to be using the deprecated Azure Access Control system, so you need to configure the validation of those tokens yourself.

You can use the [`TokenValidationParameters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.owin.security.wsfederation.wsfederationauthenticationoptions.tokenvalidationparameters(v=vs.113).aspx) option to set the same information in a way which does not prevent the default token handlers being created.

```
TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidIssuer = "https://*******.accesscontrol.windows.net/",
    SigningToken = new X509SecurityToken(...)
}
```

Comment: Hello thank you so much for your time, unfortunatly I tried those changes but it didn't work.
I got the error I use to have : `ID4037: The key needed to verify the signature could not be resolved from the following security key identifier 'SecurityKeyIdentifier
   (
   IsReadOnly = False,
   Count = 1,
   Clause[0] = X509RawDataKeyIdentifierClause(RawData =************)   Ensure that the SecurityTokenResolver is populated with the required key.`    which is more or less the same but still encrypted Couldn't it be that the answer is xml and the middleware expect json ?

Comment: Don't forget that with the web.config shown before it does works (well at least it shows me that I'm logged in with my mail but it doesn't trigger any call back and all so I'm not signed in with identity

Comment: I just noticed that you're using the old Azure Access Control system. That one doesn't publish sufficient metadata for the automated approach to work.

Comment: Well yes my company is using it and it's a requirement for my system to work with this. What should I do then ?

Comment: I'm really new to all this could you give me some lead on the signingtoken paraemeter ? Isn't my middleware only supposed to validate token ? Why should I build a token ?

Comment: Security tokens are an abstraction around a variety of mechanisms. In this case, a token (an X509 Certificate) is expected to have been used to sign the token (containing identity claims) from the ACS. Since the `SecurityTokenResolver` could not create the public key used to sign the token, you can try to create the public key token manually as a means to working around this problem.

Comment: So something along those lines ? :  `TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidAudience = "http://localhost:62569/",
                        ValidIssuer = "https://*********.accesscontrol.windows.net/",
                        IssuerSigningToken = new X509SecurityToken({}),                       
                        CertificateValidator = X509CertificateValidator.None
                    },`     thing is I have no idea how to build my x509Security Token, I'm going to look into that !