# None of the the SecurityTokenHandlers could read the 'securityToken'

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, owin, adfs

My scenario: I created a new web application having authentication using ADFS.I updated all the nuget packages and run the application.I keep getting this error :

> None of the the SecurityTokenHandlers could read the 'securityToken':

My StartUp file is as below:

```
public partial class Startup
   {
       private static string realm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Wtrealm"];
       private static string adfsMetadata = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ADFSMetadata"];

       public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
       {
           app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

           app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

           app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
               new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
               {
                   Wtrealm = realm,
                   MetadataAddress = adfsMetadata
               });

           // This makes any middleware defined above this line run before the Authorization rule is applied in web.config
           app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
       }
   }
```

Comment: Hey Keshav, can you provide the full actual error? I only see a single line of text .

Comment: This seems like a duplicate issue, Please see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31723684/owinmiddleware-authentication-ws-federation-mvc5-identity-2-idx10201-none